# How to type array with any order

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm making a filter method that receives some parameters inside an array.

```
  static all(filter?: opts) {
    console.log(filter)
  }
```

The `opts` type is like this:

```
type opts = Partial<['id', 'name', 'namePlural', 'group']>;
```

The only problem with this is that I need to make the `opts` allow the parameters in any order. With this way I can add only the parameters in the typed order.

So this works:

```
Categories.all(['id'])
```

But this don't:

```
Categories.all(['id', 'group'])
```

It ask me to put the string `name` instead `group`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does `Array<'id' | 'name' | 'namePlural' | 'group'>` work for you?  This allows both of your use cases....  It also allows duplicates like `Categories.all(['id','id','id'])`.  I know you probably don't *want* duplicates, but would the presence of duplicates really break anything?  If duplicates are okay, I'll write this up as an answer.  If they are not, can you elaborate on the use case to show what breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `'id', 'name', 'namePlural', 'group'` are properties on an object you want to filter (say `Person`).

In that case you can do (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-array-parameters?file=keyof.ts):

```
// assumed declared elsewhere
interface Person {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  namePlural: string;
  group: string;
}

function all(filter?: opts) {
  console.log(filter);
}

type opts = (keyof Person)[];

all(["id"]);
all(["id", "group"]);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to change anything if fields are added or removed from `Person`.

Otherwise you can do something like @jcalz has recommended (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-array-parameters?file=index.ts):

```
function all(filter?: opts) {
  console.log(filter);
}

type opts = ('id' | 'name' | 'namePlural' | 'group')[];

all(["id"]);
all(["id", "group"]);
```

Note that neither of these are restricted to unique values, if that is a requirement.

Comment: Really thank you, that way is away better than what I was trying to do.